# Question Regarding Solvability of finite group G.

Tags: galois-theory, solvable-groups

[image]

I would like to clarify my proof(Sketch) for part A:

We know that $G_{n-1}$ is finite and abelian(i.e. $G_{n-1}/\{e\}$ is abelian ) therefore it is solvable. Since, $G_{n-2}/G_{n-1}$ is finite and abelian it is also solvable. Therefore, $G_{n-2}$ is solvable (Since $G_{n-1}$ is normal in 
$G_{n-2}$). Continuing in this manner we can show that $G_1$ and $G_0/G_1$ is solvable therefore G is solvable. Is this valid?

Comment: What is your definition of "solvable"? To me, it's _exactly_ (a) (or at least that (a) is possible to achieve).

Comment: $[G_{i-1}:G_{i}]$ is prime and $G_i$ is normal in $G_{i-1}$

Comment: That makes sense. OK. Then I think the intended proof is to take $G_i\subseteq G_{i+1}$, and then show that you can _insert_ more groups in-between them so that the quotients have prime orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly valid. But it may not be enough, depending on what the exercise assume known. That is, you are using the fact that for $N \subseteq G$ a normal subgroup, $N$ solvable and $G/N$ solvable imply that $G$ is. This is true, but if you are not sure why, you should write a proof.

Comment: Yes i have proved that theorem Thanks